# jslint camelcase and dot notation conflict

Tags: jslint, meta, jshint

This issue is some what silly and can be solved by ignoring camelcase or dot notation. What I'm curious about is how are other people handling cases where you're parsing JSON that contain underscores. I prefer to use dot notation (it's cleaner, less characters, and so on) but I also like to enforce camelcase. Can I have my cake and eat it with out jshint/jslint throwing a tantrum?

Comment: How do you run JSHint? You can configure it to not issue the warnings in question when linting `.json` files.

Comment: I can configure it, but at the same time I would like it to enforce both. My solution to the problem was to use inline jshint configuration. I'm only dealing with camel case in places where I'm consuming api's or third party data sources. I use the inline configs in only the files where it's unavoidable.